# Callback via inheritance vs object reference

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, callback

Compare the following two variants (that should do the same thing)

```
class Foo
    {
    public:
        void void doStuff()
            {
            //...
            doStuffImpl();
            //...
            }

        virtual void doStuffImpl()=0;
        void affectStateInFoo()
            {}
    };

class Bar:public Foo
    {
    public:
        void doStuffImpl()
            {
            affectStateInFoo();
            }
    };
```

And

```
class Foo;

class Callback
    {
    public:
        virtual void doStuff(Foo& foo)=0;
    };

class Foo
    {
    public:
        Foo(Callback& o):obj(o){}

        void void doStuff()
            {
            //...
            obj.doStuff(*this);
            //...
            }

        void affectStateInFoo()
            {}

        Callback& obj;
    };

class Bar:public Callback
    {
    public:
        void doStuff(Foo& foo)
            {
            foo.affectStateInFoo();
            }
    };
```

When is one of the two variants to prefer?

Comment: Probably a better question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) though. :)

Comment: I'd prefer a more generic way, by means of `std::function` (or `boost::function`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method requires `Bar` to inherit from `Foo`, which closely couples these classes. For callbacks this is not always what you want to do. Your second method doesn't require this.

I would use the first method if you actually extending a class, but for notifications I would use the second approach, or as Igor R. mentioned in the comments a function pointer like object.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the second one because it is more unit-testable with mocks. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Overdoing stuff per inheritance is a common failure to newcomers of object orientation.

Using delegation, you called it callback, is in common more flexible.

- Less numbers of classes
- possible reuse of "callback" class
- Exchangeable at runtime instead of compiletime